# how to deploy the SOAP Webapp to Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, soap

I've just completed the deployment of the Tomcat Application Server on my mac, but I don't know how to deploy the SOAP webapp to Tomcat.

I couldn't find a suitable tutorial which explains this for mac OS. Can anyone give me a link to such a tutorial or explain how could this be done ? Im really stuck in this !

Many thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created a .war file, you can just copy it to the webapps dir in your tomcat installation. After you've copied it, tomcat (assuming it's running) will unpack the war file and start up your webapp. After that's been done, you can check it out at http://yourhost/webappname. You can find the tomcat documentation at [tomcat.apache.org](http://tomcat.apache.org/)